# How can I update the address that a variable stand for?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int a = 1 ;
int*p = &a;
(*p) = 2;
```

if &a is 6422312 , and I want to update the value in 6422312 to 2(int), but still keep the value of int a = 1

So I want to let &a become 6422316 and assign value 1, that is, I want to use the same name "a" as 1 later whether it is in 64222312 or not.

```
//how can I do this
&a => 6422316  
*(&a) <- 1;
```

I know I can easily do this if I treat "a" as a pointer, but I want to know if I can use the variable to do same thing.

Comment: You cannot do that. What are you trying to achieve? Please explain that more so that someone can tell you how to do it properly.

Comment: You cannot change the location of a variable

Comment: @Mat  I want to use the same variable name "a" (not a pointer) as value 1 later , and also change the value in the address of a.

Comment: @harold But I just want to use the same box name and let it stand for another box. Is it impossible for the language?

Comment: I cannot see the problem? With the three lines in your first code box, a WILL have the value 2.

Comment: Assuming you could do this, how would you decide whether`a` would refer to the first or second value?

Comment: if you want another variable, why don't just allocate memory for it and copy data from a?

Comment: *"I want to use the same variable name "a" (not a pointer) as value 1 later , and also change the value in the address of a."* It's impossible and makes no sense. It's like saying "I want to sell my house, but I also want to keep the house with the address of my house".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No I just want to keep my house's name, and use the name to build a new one in another address. But it seems that the address of this house's name can not be changed?

Comment: Yup, you can't change variable addresses in C. If you want to store 2 different numbers, you need 2 variables.

Comment: @Jeffese Exactly why do you want to do this? I cannot imagine any scenario where it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any kind of control over the address of a variable in `C` (except custom compiler extensions). That means you cannot choose its address. The compiler does that. Moreover a variable in `C` does not change its address over its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do that is somewhat similar to your description is pointer arithmetic. So let's say that you have a pointer `p` and you want to change the value that lies `sizeof *p` bytes after `p` to 42, then use `*(p+1) = 42`.